# Submitting form and showing content on same view on Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple question-and-answer forum on ROR5 and I'm stuck on submitting an answer for every question.

In the respective questions/:id SHOW view, I have a texteditor where users can submit an answer to the question. The answer will then be posted to the same page where the question is. As you can see in the view and the answers controller, I have tried to link the form to the answer model through a answer controller.

I seem to have problems with the routing, because when I click 'Submit', I get:

### The Error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: question
```

### Server log

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 15:19:39 +0800
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bM4INetkQj94Hy1t64zVLEvIGCumUjLZpA6LwHNT0qTRjYHLYpkpcTw42ulOVNDePsYCAG5puco5AEl+nA6bGw==", "answer"=>{"answercontent"=>"<p>dqwdqwd</p>"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: question):

app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:24:in `question_params'
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

How can I improve my code to fix this issue?

Here are parts of my code:

### /questions/:id (SHOW view)

```
<div class="description-wrap">
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Country:</h1> 
                <p><%= @question.country %></p>

                <h1>Educational Level:</h1> 
                <p><%= @question.educational_level %></p>

                <h1>Topic:</h1> 
                <p><%= @question.topic %></p>
            </div>

            <br> <!-- jQuery action to scroll down to text editor -->
            <a href=''><button type="button" class="btn">Answer this Question</button></a>

        </div>
    </div> 

   <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
   <!-- Answers submitted by users will be shown here -->

   <%= user.profilepicture_url %>
   <%= user.userid %>
   <%= answer.answercontent %>

   <!-- Submit Answer Form -->
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10 editor">    
        <%= form_for :answer, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_area :answercontent, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 90 %> 
            <%= tinymce %>
            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
        <% end %>
   </div>
```

As you can see, I am using a TinyMCE editor for the text area. This works fine.

### Question model

The Question model has five params:

```
t.string :picture_url
t.string :country
t.string :educational_level
t.string :topic
t.integer :user_id
```

### questions_controller.rb

And the controller looks like this

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @question = Question.all
end

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @question = Question.new
end

def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)

  @question.save
  redirect_to @question
end

private
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:picture_url, :country, :educational_level, :topic)
  end
end
```

### Answer model

Answer model has 3 params:

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :question_id
t.string :answercontent
```

### answers_controller.rb

And the controller looks like this.

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

def new
    # i think something is wrong here too..
    @answer = Question.show
end

def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    render :new

  @answer.save
  # is this part correct?
  redirect_to "/questions/#{question.id}"
end

private
  def answer_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:user_id, :question_id, :answercontent)
  end
end
```

### Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'home#index'

get 'profile/index' => 'profile#index'

# is this 'post' route correct?
post 'questions/:id' => "answers#create"

resources :users 
resources :questions 
resources :answers

end
```

Also, please do comment if I can improve this question in any way. Thanks.

Comment: Is it going to `answers#create` method? Also show us your routes.

Comment: You have messed up `answers_controller` btw.

Comment: @Pavan Oh right, forgot the most important one. I will edit now! (I do have a POST route going to answers#create, but I am not sure if it's correct.)

Comment: Can you add the server log when you click on submit?

Comment: @Pavan I've added on the routes and the server log! I'm quite new to controllers so yeah, I must have messed up a lot there :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> param is missing or the value is empty: question

For the error, you are submitting the form to `questions#create` instead of `answers#create`, so `question_params` expects `:question` key to be present in the `params hash` , so is the error.

You should edit the form like below

```
<%= form_for :answer, url: answers_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :answercontent, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 90 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, @question.id %>
  <%= tinymce %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Also in the `answers_controller`, your `answer_params` should be like this

```
def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:user_id, :question_id, :answercontent)
end
```

Your `answers#create` is wrong, it should like below

```
def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:answer][:question_id]
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
  if @answer.save
    redirect_to @question
  else
    render :new #you might have to consider changing this to suite your case
  end
end
```

Additional, though its not related to what you are doing, the `answers#new` is also wrong. It should be

```
def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked nicely.